# Visualizing more than one logs in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorboard

So I'm trying to achieve something like this in tensorboard where in the Run section, i can see all the logs being selected together and displayed on graph in tensorboard.

[image]

But i couldn't seem to get this when i run tensorboard where i can only specify one directory with

```
tensorboard --logdir=models/dnn_momentum/test
```

where i have:

[image]

Hence in tensorboard, i only have:

[image]

Is there any commands that i can use to allow tensorboard to access all three files logs at the same time hence allowing me to view all of them at the Runs section of tensorboard like the first image above?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to view all the logs in the three directories by pointing TensorBoard at the parent directory:

```
tensorboard --logdir=models
```

Alternatively, you could pass a comma separated list of directories:

```
tensorboard --logdir=models/dnn_momentum,models/dnn_adam,models/dnn_adagrad
```